# How to bind an enum object to the background of a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding, background-color

I want to bind the background color of a button to an enum. I wonder if there is an enum object that can hold multiple values, for example the state and the color. I want to avoid two enums that could be out of sync. Here are two enums that I would like to integrate with each other.

```
enum StateValue { Player, Wall, Box }
enum StateColor { Colors.Red, Colors.Grey, Colors.Brown }
```

Then I need to create a binding for the XAML button.

```
<Button Content="Player" Background="{Binding Source=...?}" />
```

Maybe, a dictionary like the following is helpful. But still I do not know how the binding needs to be written.

```
public Dictionary<StateValue, Color> stateValueColor = 
new Dictionary<ElementState, Color>()
{
 { StateValue.Player, Colors.Red },
 { StateValue.Wall, Colors.Grey },
 { StateValue.Box, Colors.Brown }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

I would advise you to use a custom converter for that, and only supply the enum from code-behind (or ViewModel).

This would look like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(StateValue), typeof(Color))]
public class StateValueColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!(value is StateValue))
            throw new ArgumentException("value not of type StateValue");
        StateValue sv = (StateValue)value;
        //sanity checks
        switch (sv)
            {
                case StateValue.Player:
                return Colors.Red;
                //etc
            }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       Color c = (value as Color);
       if(c == Colors.Red)
         return StateValue.Player;
       //etc
    }
}
```

And in wpf:

```
<Button 
  Content="Player" 
  Background="{Binding Source=StateValue, 
    Converter={StaticResource stateValueColorConverter}}" />
```

Of course, if you are using a DI container, you could provide different implementations of the interface with changing colours, just let your view get a converter injected and supply that via binding to the converter property of the binding.

Note: this code was written without compiler, I'm not sure if the xaml is 100% correct, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Femaref! But I get error CS0077 which states: `The "as" operator can be used with any *nullable* type - which is references and Nullable<T> types.`. In detail the cast `StateValue sv = (value as StateValue);` is not accepted since StateValue is an enum.

Comment: The enum cannot be `null`. That is why the error occurs. Your type check is good but does not help with the cast problem, though.

Comment: Further, for testing I return the Color value resp. the enum Value hard coded. That does not change my buttons background color. Instead, it looses the default background color.

Answer (score 4):

To return the correct type one needs to write `return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);` in `StateValueColorConverter`. This solves the problem of the lost background color.